# Why is this a quadratic programming problem?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm very new.

How would I minimize the following objective?

$\sum_{k=1}^p\| I_{k} - M_{k}A \|^2$

Each I and M are known.

I am told I can use a quadratic programming solver, but I am not sure how it applies.
Could someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: Are $I_k$, $M_k$, $A$ scalars, vectors, matrices, ...?

Comment: sorry l2 norm, and I is a vector, M is a matrix and A is a vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is quadratic because you are using the $\ell^2$ norm, i.e., for a real vector $\bf v$ you have $\Vert {\bf v} \Vert^2=\sum_{j=1}^n v_j^2 = {\bf v}^\top {\bf v}$.

For a given vector ${\bf i}$ of length $n$ and matrix $M$ you have
$$\Vert {\bf i}-M {\bf a}\Vert^2 
= ({\bf i}-M{\bf a})^\top ({\bf i} -M{\bf a})={\bf i}^\top {\bf i} - 2 {\bf i}^\top M{\bf a} + {\bf a}^\top M^\top M {\bf a}.$$

If you rewrite your objective $f({\bf a})$ this way you have
$$\begin{align}f({\bf a}) 
&= \sum_{k=1}^p \Vert {\bf i}_k - M_k {\bf a}\Vert^2 
\\&= \sum_{k=1}^p \left( {\bf i}_k^\top {\bf i}_k - 2 {\bf i}_k^\top M_k{\bf a} + {\bf a}^\top M_k^\top M_k {\bf a} \right)
\\&= \left(\sum_{k=1}^p {\bf i}_k^\top {\bf i}_k\right) - 2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^p {\bf i}_k^\top M_k\right) {\bf a} + {\bf a}^\top \left( \sum_{k=1}^p M_k^\top M_k \right) {\bf a} .
\end{align}
$$
As @Rahul pointed out in the comment spurring a rewrite of this answer, you can see the constant term, the linear term, and the quadratic term.
This is a quadratic problem in ${\bf a}$, and is convex.

Rewriting just shows it's quadratic, you don't need to rewrite it to take its Jacobian:
$$\nabla f({\bf a}) = \sum_{k=2}^p -2 M_k^\top ({\bf i}_k - M_k {\bf a}),$$
or its Hessian:
$$\nabla^2 f({\bf a}) = \sum_{k=1}^p 2 M_k^\top M_k.$$
You can easily see from this representation that it's a convex problem, and any point where $$\nabla f({\bf a})=\vec 0$$ is a solution.

Comment: Probably easier to do $\|\mathbf i_k-\mathbf M_k\mathbf a\|^2 = (\mathbf i_k-\mathbf M_k\mathbf a)^\intercal(\mathbf i_k-\mathbf M_k\mathbf a) = \mathbf i_k^\intercal\mathbf i_k - 2\mathbf i_k^\intercal\mathbf M_k\mathbf a+\mathbf a^\intercal\mathbf M_k^\intercal\mathbf M_k\mathbf a$, from where you can immediately see a constant term (which can be ignored), a linear term, and a quadratic term.

Comment: Many thanks, this is so understandable